# How to get push notifications from website to android app?

Tags: android

I am developing an android web app which needs to get a push notifications from a particular website for content change for that page. How am I suppose to do that?

Comment: one link answer: www.google.com,

Comment: Go through [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't have a straight forward answer but I would try to give a brief overview.

First you need to create a **REST API** to send a notification on android phones.
Use **Firebase Cloud Messaging** for that.(Firebase might be a whole new topic for you so go through this [link](http://firebase.google.com).)

[Here's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) a documentation to use REST API to send a notification to an android app.

Now use this API calls to send notification when something important on a website happens.

Once again Firebase Cloud Messaging might be nnew for you, so try to get go some search about Firebase and Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Thank you sir i will surely looking forward to it ??